# Doens't working for loop in swing worker class

Tags: java, swing, http, swingworker

Maybe there is a mistake I did. But I can't fix this problem. The `for` loop in Swing Worker Class doesn't working.

```
public class _5Strategy_A extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

_4HttpRequest_Naver attk = new _4HttpRequest_Naver();

int num_acc;
int time ;
int total_post;
int total_comment;
int init = 0;
int execute = 0;
int i = 0;
int c = 0; 
static int k = 0;
static int response = 0;        
private boolean _suspended = false;

public synchronized void suspend() { _suspended = true; notify(); }
public synchronized void resume() { _suspended = false; notify(); }

  @Override
protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {

  init = 0;
  publish(new Integer[] { init }); //
  _1SetProxy.setProxy();

  init = 1;
  publish(new Integer[] { init });  // 
  _3SetTarget_NaverPopular25.setTarget_Naver();
  _3SetTarget_NaverRise50.setTarget_NaverUp50();
  new _3SetTarget_NaverRise50(10);

// ***************************************************************** //  
// ***************************************************************** //  
  for (int ch=0; ch<5; ch++){
        System.out.println("Obviously This statement could be shown 5 times.")
 // ***************************************************************** //  

  for (k=0; k<2; k++){

       synchronized(this) {
              while (_suspended == true) {
                  wait(); // The current thread will block until some else calls notify()
                  // Then if _suspended is false, it keeps looping the for
              }
          }

  init = 2;
  publish(new Integer[] { init });

    String page = attk.GetLoginPage_Naver(_0Storing.url);
    String raw = String.valueOf(_9AccountsManager.tableNaverAccounts_A.getModel().getValueAt(0, num_acc));
    String[] raw_splited = raw.split(":");
    String id = raw_splited[0];
    String pw = raw_splited[1];
    String postParams = attk.getFormParams(page, id, pw);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());

  init = 3;
  publish(new Integer[] { init }); 

    // POST 
    attk.loginNaver(_0Storing.url, postParams);
    response = 0; // Initializing response code.

  init = 4;
  publish(new Integer[] { init });

         // POST
        try {
            attk.AttackNaver(_0Storing.baseURL, String.valueOf(GUI.proxyTable.getModel().getValueAt(k%17, 0)), Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(GUI.proxyTable.getModel().getValueAt(k%17, 1))), _3SetTarget_NaverPopular25.attkParam[k%34]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                }

    System.out.println(+k+" looping.");
   }

   num_acc++; 
   k=0;
   init=1;


  }


  // ***************************************************************** //
  // ***************************************************************** //  

  return null;
  } // End of doInBackground()

  protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {

  /* Initialization */
    if(init==0){

        _0Storing.addRow("GET", "Checking", _1SetProxy.proxy_url, "LOCAL");

    }

    if(init==1){

        _0Storing.setRst("OK");
        _0Storing.addRow("GET", "Targetting", "http://finance.naver.com/sise/lastsearch2.nhn", "LOCAL"); 

    }     

    if(init==2){

        _0Storing.setRst("OK");
        _0Storing.addRow("GET", "Extracting", _0Storing.url, "LOCAL"); 

    }

    if(init==3){

        _0Storing.setRst("OK");
        _0Storing.addRow("POST", "Login...("+_9AccountsManager.tableNaverAccounts_A.getModel().getValueAt(0, num_acc)+")", _0Storing.url, "LOCAL"); 

      }

    if(init==4){

        _0Storing.setRst("OK");

        try {
        _0Storing.addRow("POST", _3SetTarget_NaverPopular25.text[k%24], _3SetTarget_NaverPopular25.code[k%24], String.valueOf(GUI.proxyTable.getModel().getValueAt(k%17, 0)));      
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        }

    }

    }

  @Override
  protected void done() {
    if (isCancelled())
      _0Storing.addLog("\nCancelled !");
    else{
        GUI.bottomStatus.setText("Finish !");
        if (response == 0)
        GUI.mainTable.setValueAt("OK", GUI.mainTable.getRowCount()-1, 5);
        else
        GUI.mainTable.setValueAt("FAILED", GUI.mainTable.getRowCount()-1, 5);
    }
   }

}
```

Above code is my code. Sorry to dirty and complicated. but I can't summary it because I don't know what is the cause of this problem. please concentrate on //*******// for loop. maybe my statement could be shown in console 5 times. but I can see that only 1 time. Please Tell me why this for loop doesn't working. Thank you.

Comment: As a start, you missed the ";" after that statement.

Comment: This is not your code. If it was you will know what is the reason of the lock. And the code look suspicious to me.

Answer (score 1):

Both of the following blocks are `synchronized` on the same object (`this`):

```
public synchronized void resume() { _suspended = false; notify(); }
```

and

```
synchronized(this) {
    while (_suspended == true) {
        wait(); // The current thread will block until some else calls notify()
        // Then if _suspended is false, it keeps looping the for
    }
}
```

So you have a deadlock.  You'll never be able to `resume()` while the SwingWorker is in the `wait()` state because synchronization won't allow it.  For more information on synchronization, I'd recommend looking at the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) and specifically the section on [Intrinsic Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

On a side note, I wash my hands clean of any evil you're planning to do with this code. It did make me chortle to see `attk = new _4HttpRequest_Naver();`

Answer (score 0):

It is a matter of taste, but I don't actually like the way concurrency is managed here.  I suggest you eliminate all that loops, the wait(), etc., and just make your SwingWorker to block itself into a BlockingQueue reading.  Something like:

```
public static BlockingQueue<WorkerCommand> queue =
   new ArrayBlockingQueue<WorkerCommand>();

// WorkerCommand is a simple bean with a getter and a setter for the command

// ....

boolean keepOn = true;
while (keepOn) { 
   WorkerCommand command = queue.poll(); // blocking!
   if (command.getCommand().equals(COMMAND_STOP)) { keepOn = false; }
   else {
       // whatever you need
   }
}

// Clients just put commands into the queue, which makes the worker to wake up, consume and
//   serve the command
```

This way you manage your concurrency using high-level java facilities and can focus in doing whatever is your heavy task.  And this way, it escalates easily if you need more Workers in some moment.